# Comparing Two Dimensional Arrays in C without strcmp

Tags: c, if-statement, multidimensional-array, do-while, stdio

```
char status = 'f';
char arr1[11][11];
char arr2[11][11];
......

do{
......
  for(int x=0; x<11; x++){
  for(int y=0; y<11; y++){
        if(temp[x][y]!=store[x][y]){
            status='f';
            }
        else{
            status='t';
            }
        }}
}
while(status != 'f');
......
```

The above is my code for a `do`-`while` loop.

From my knowledge, when the condition within `while` is true, the program should run again from `do`.

Assuming my understanding is correct, when `temp[x][y]` does not equal to `store[x][y]`, the program should let `status = 'f'` and the loop continues. Once `temp` and `store` are equal, `status = 't'` and the loop will end.

My problem now is that while I am able to proc the loop, the loop wont end even when `temp` and `store` are equal. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 else{
    status='t';
    break;
 }
```

Will ensure that you don't overwrite the once changed `status`. Otherwise it is overwritten.

And also another check inside first for loop for

`if ( status == 't') break;`

---

Code will be

```
do{
status = 't'; // denotes that they are equal intiially.
......
    for(int x=0; x<11; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y<11; y++) {
            if(temp[x][y]!=store[x][y]) {
                status='f'; // they are not equal
            }
        }
        if( status == 'f')
            break;
    }
} while(status == 'f');
```

Comment: Do I need a specific directory to use `break`?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant directive

Comment: I need the `do...while` loop... If I removed it, how else can I check the 2d array over and over again?

Comment: @Raph.: You want to check until the two arrays become equal right?

Comment: @coderredoc How does the loop end this way? Does the `status` revert back to `t` every time the loop happens?

Comment: @Raph.: Yes you need to intilaize it to `t` every beginning of the loop